# PHP: check if a property doesn't exist or its value is an empty string

Tags: php, isset

This probably has been asked, but I couldn't find the exact answer I am seeking.

In javascript, I can simply do

```
if (a.b) {//do something}
```

But in PHP, if I do

```
if($a->b) {}
```

Basically it'll work, but I will get a notice if `a` has no `b`, so I switch to

```
if(isset($a->b)){}
```

That doesn't work because when `a->b` is an empty string, it will return true. So I ended up doing

```
if(isset($a->b) && $a->b !== ''){}
```

This seems redundant and not very bug-proof.

What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: You could use php empty (http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), but there are som possible drawbacks to this as well. Empty checks if the value is null, an empty string, an empty array, is 0, and a few more scenarios. The full list is in the manual.

Comment: I think that will also trigger notice about trying to get non-existing property

Comment: yes you are right! This should be the answer

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

`empty` checks if a variable is set, and contains data. If it's empty or not set, it will return true.

`if(!empty($a->b)) {}`

Comment: Instead of `if(isset($a->) && !empty($a->b)) {}`, try `if(isset($a) && !empty($a->b)) {}` (without the arryow on `$a`)

Comment: why can't I just use `if (!empty($a->b)){}`? Providing that `empty` also checks `isset`.

Comment: You totally can... Just checked the docs, I didn't realise empty checked if a var was set. Yeah... just use empty :)